# Installing Chrome RDP Host on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop

Every time I attempt to install Chrome Remote desktop on my machine so it can be shared as an end point, I am directed to a listing in the Ubuntu App Store. When I press "Install" the install button seems to change to "Installing" then to "Remove" (to indicate full install) almost instantaneously.

When I attempt to go back into Chrome RDP, I am still told I need to install Chrome RDP host (chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb).I then run sudo apt-get dpkg -i * (* is the chrome rdp file), then sudo apt-get install -f, which proceeds to tell me 0 have installed.

Has anyone else had this experience as well? Having trouble figuring out why this keeps happening. Does it have anything to do with that it was meant for debian, and I'm using Ubuntu?

Any recommendations to help resolve would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE: Here is the output of sudo dpkg -i chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb.

```
 (Reading database ... 274322 files and directories currently 
  installed.)
  Preparing to unpack chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb ...
  Unpacking chrome-remote-desktop (61.0.3163.20) over 
  (61.0.3163.20) ...
  Setting up chrome-remote-desktop (61.0.3163.20) ...
  Shutting down Chrome Remote Desktop hosts (they will restart 
  automatically)...
  Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu19) ...
  Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
```

Comment: The correct syntax is `sudo dpkg -i chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb`. Try this way and relate results

Comment: Yes, thats what I did, let me edit the post.

Comment: So, since you will edit it, post output of this command I told you, regarding you have to be where chrome*.deb was downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

The "simplest" way to install a deb package is to download it and run dpkg.

Ubuntu App Store can do it, but not always it show you why it couldn't install a package. There several issues, as broken dependences, for example.

After download a package, you must be within the path where this deb was downloaded:

```
cd /path/where/was/downloaded
sudo dpkg -i chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb
```

or

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/where/was/downloaded/chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb
```

Hint: You can use wildcards to do it, as:

`sudo dpkg -i c*deb` if it's the only c-beginning .deb filename in this path

`sudo dpkg -i c*` if it's the only c-beginning filename in this path

`sudo dpkg -i *` if it's the only .deb file in this path

dpkg will verbose output so we could run after faulting or broken packages. We  can successfully install several packages following dpkg clues.

Comment: Thank you. When I run this I get the error as mentioned in the update in the update to the original question. No obvious errors appear to show up

Comment: You must `sudo apt -f install` to complete faulty dependences. [Use this  as reference](https://www.everything-linux-101.com/how-to/remote-control/chrome-remote-desktop-install-for-linux/). Start at step 2.

Comment: I run this, get no errors, but still can't enable the sharing function on the remote desktop app, it says I have to install it again

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Installing Chrome browser and using RDP as a spoke of Chrome Browser (rather than Chromium) seems to resolve the issue. I'm now able to set up the connection.

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Why google does not focus on it ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
Installed the deb as instructed and did sudo apt -f install 
No error message and install worked as seen below

```
$ sudo dpkg -i chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb 
[sudo] password for XXXXXX: 
(Reading database ... 498837 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking chrome-remote-desktop (71.0.3578.36) over (71.0.3578.36) ...
Setting up chrome-remote-desktop (71.0.3578.36) ...
Shutting down Chrome Remote Desktop hosts (they will restart automatically)...
insserv: warning: script 'asperarund' missing LSB tags and overrides
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.9) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
```

but when I open remote and ask to share, I get over and over again the request to install the deb

I rebooted between two installs!
what next?

PS: regarding the warning, should I do as in https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=379